# Adding text to google maps polyline icon

Tags: google-maps, svg, google-polyline

I'm trying to add text to a polyline [icons property](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#PolylineOptions).

The icon's path property can follow the [SVG path notation](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/paths.html#PathData).
What I'm looking for is an svg representation using path notation for letters A-Z and numbers 0-9.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SO is not a search-engine for any kind of ressources, here an explanation how you may easily create these paths on your own  instead(using [**inkscape**](https://inkscape.org) )

1. open a new document
2. use the text-tool(there's a button with an "A" or hit <kbd>F8</kbd>)  and type the desired number/letter
3. hit <kbd>F1</kbd> and move the object to the top-left corner of the drawing
4. from the top-menu select path->object to path
5. save the document as **plain svg**
6. Open the SVG with a text-editor and you'll see the path somewhere in the document

Instead of saving the SVG you may also use the code-explorer to get the path (<kbd>CTRL+SHIFT+X</kbd>)

2 samples created via this method:

**A:**

```
m 0,28.362183 10.996094,-28.63281288 4.082031,0 11.71875,28.63281288 -4.316406,0 -3.339844,-8.671875 -11.9726563,0 -3.1445312,8.671875 z m 8.2617188,-11.757813 9.7070312,0 -2.988281,-7.9296874 c -0.911473,-2.4088321 -1.588555,-4.3879967 -2.03125,-5.9375 -0.364596,1.8359613 -0.878919,3.6588762 -1.542969,5.46875 z
```

**Z:**

```
M 0,28.362183 0,24.846558 14.667969,6.5067139 c 1.04165,-1.3020602 2.031232,-2.4348716 2.96875,-3.3984375 l -15.9765628,0 0,-3.37890628 20.5078128,0 0,3.37890628 -16.074219,19.8632816 -1.7382813,2.011718 18.2812503,0 0,3.378907 z
```

Demo: [**http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/jkwyd46h/**](http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/jkwyd46h/)